# Change appended td by condition inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, append

I am appending rows and columns to a table using javascript. But I need one of the classname inside the `td` to somethings else based on the condition inside a `$.post() response.

I did this:

```
let arr = ['Hermione', 'Ron', 'Harry']

arr.forEach(d=>{
    $('#the_table>tbody').append(` 
                <tr id='tr_${d}'>
                    <td'>${d}</td>
                    <td><i id='change' class='no'></i></td>
                </tr>
            `);
});

const myfunc = () => {
$.post(api, json_object,
    function(data, status) {
        if (data.value === 'started') {
        setTimeout(myfunc, 5000);
    } else {
        $('#change').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
        }
}, 'json');
            }
myfunc();
```

When I do this, it is only changing the value for the first value (`Hermione`). But in the console.log, I can see that the `data.value` is not `started` so it should've changed to `yes`.

Hoe can I change it to `yes` for each of the rows once the condition has been passed

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` value which is not allowed. You need to figure out a way to distinguish them (you could use the index in the `.forEach` but you would also need to return an index from your `.post` call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#change').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
```

you need to fix this selector $('#change')

i dont know if the api return has id

but you need to select it like this

```
$(`tr#${data.something} #change`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide JSfiddle or any online code setup to debug more? I could see there is first  element is having a single quote that is not being ignored.
${d} should be like this ${d}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You are using the same `id name` for identifying many differents rows .
Each `ID`  must be unique . So if you have many elements to manipulate it is better to identify them by their `classname` instead . Change the the the attribute `ID` to `CLASS` as illustrated below .

```
 // I have only change the attribute id to class
 let arr = ['Hermione', 'Ron', 'Harry']

 arr.forEach(d=>{
 $('#the_table>tbody').append(` 
     <tr id='tr_${d}'>
       <td'>${d}</td>
       <td><i class='change' class='no'></i></td>// now their identified by class name
            </tr>
        `);
  });

 const myfunc = () => {
 $.post(api, json_object,
     function(data, status) {
         if (data.value === 'started') {
             setTimeout(myfunc, 5000);
         } else {
            $('.change').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');  
         }
     }, 'json');
 }

 myfunc();
```